# Using DOMs in conjuction with For loop to create table; populate table with an array? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am looking to create a table from a string array using for loops and DOMs.  I wanted to just have one variable with all my table data in it, and then use loops to take each individual string out of the data variable and put it into a cell, which then goes into a row, which then goes into the table.  Wanting to result in a 3x3 table with the first three strings in my data variable being the column headers.  I thought something like this would work, but I'm not getting any results:

---

```
var createTable = document.createElement("table"); //creates the Table

document.body.appendChild(createTable); //inserts the table into the body of the html page



var data = ["Car", "Top Speed", "Price", "Chevrolet", "120mph", "$10,000", "Pontiac", "140mph", "$20,000"];

for (var r=0; r < 3; r++) {



var row = document.createElement("tr"); //creates a row

for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {

    var cell = document.createElement("td"); //creates a cell
    cell.appendChild(data[x]); //puts each data array item, in order, into each cell?
}

row.appendChild(cell); //puts cells into row
createTable.appendChild(row); //puts rows into table

}
```

---

Any suggestions as to what I'm overlooking or not understanding would be great. Thank you!

Comment: You will need to restructure your data logically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/ADukg/30331/)

I'm writing the details:

In the first for, you need to run: 0 -> 3, 3 -> 6, 6 -> 9

That's why your first index is: `r * 3`
and last index is calculated by: `r * 3 + 3`

For r=0 you get 0->2, etc

In addition, you need to insert the table to the body.
Otherwise, it's created but do nothing.